# Redirect to blank page before intended page - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When using the redirect method, it takes me to a white page with the URL printed on the screen that I am redirecting to, before finally redirecting to that page. Any reason why it's not redirecting DIRECTLY to the intended page?

Here is the code I'm using: return Redirect::route('cidade.index');

Has anyone else experienced this?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqNL0.png

```
web.php
Route::middleware('autenticacao')->prefix('sistema')->group(function () {
  Route::get('/lista', [CidadeController::class, 'index'])->name('cidade.index');

      Route::get('editar/{id}/edit', [CidadeController::class, 'edit'])
      ->name('cidade.edit'); 
      Route::post('update/{id}', [CidadeController::class, 'update'])->name('update');


      Route::get('desativar/{id}', [CidadeController::class, 'destroy']);
      Route::get('ativar/{id}', [CidadeController::class, 'active']);
});
```

```
CidadeController.php

    public function update(Request $request)
    {
        // Validation for required fields (and using some regex to validate our numeric value)
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'id' => 'required',
                    'nome' => 'required',
                    'uf' => 'required',
        
                ])->validate();
        Cidade::where('id', $request->id)->update(['nome' => $request->nome, 'uf' => $request->uf]);
        $cidades = Cidade::orderBy('status', 'DESC')->get();

        return redirect()->route('cidade.index')
            ->with('success','Product updated successfully');
    }

   

    public function destroy(int $id)
    {
        Cidade::where([
            ['id', $id],
            ['status', true]
        ])->update(['status' => false]);
        return redirect()->route('cidade.index');
    }


    public function active(int $id)
    {
        Cidade::where([
            ['id', $id],
            ['status', false]
        ])->update(['status' => true]);

        return Redirect::route('cidade.index');
    }
}
```

Comment: It's redirecting to sistema/lista, which isn't shown here. Maybe there's an intermediate redirect somewhere?

Comment: In the route list can't able to see cidade.index have you added that